# How can I know the file size of the downloaded file before downloading it?

Tags: download

How can I know the file size of the downloaded file before downloading it?

Comment: I am not sure can you.  Can you give a clearer example? What browser are you using?

Comment: I think you should at least specify the protocol in your question, because you can download files in many ways: over HTTP, FTP, rsync, scp, bittorrent etc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following command:

```
curl --head <url>
```

where `<url>` is the URL of the file you want. The response will be only the headers of the HTTP response, which may include the file size if is known by the server.

Comment: How does this help with FTP or SCP?

Comment: @Ignacio Both of those are used predominately with client programs that commonly provide that information already. HTTP is much more likely. You should probably ask the person asking instead.

Comment: Which *may* include the file size. If it's something that's being built and streamed on demand, the file size may not be known.