# How to know the size of a file before downloading it?

Tags: windows-7, windows, download

I'm on Windows 7. How to know the size of a file before downloading it?

I have Chrome, Firefox and Orbit downloaders. Sometimes they don't show the file size of a download no matter what, for example none of them are showing [the file size of this driver](http://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp55001-55500/sp55032.exe)

Is there a command prompt command to show the file or something?

my question is exactly [like this one](https://superuser.com/questions/293696/how-can-i-know-the-filesize-of-the-downloaded-file-before-downloading-it) but on Windows.

Comment: Both IDM and Opera seemed to show the size for me. Will try IE too ;-)

Comment: @hjpotter92 would you please tell me the size? :)

Comment: @Fischer: The answer to the other question uses curl. You can too.

Comment: @Karan curl on windows? never tried it, i'll try now :)

Comment: Yeah, I use curl and wget regularly on Windows.

Comment: 338.94 [MiB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mibibyte)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you download a file without seeing the final file size, then the server side is actually not sending this information along with the file that you're downloading.

As a programmer sometimes I do not know the final file size because I create the download results on the fly, and the only way to know it before sending it, is to save it locally first, gzip and then measure the size.

To me if the downloaded file is not showing the final file size, the only way to know it is to first download it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FreeDownloadmanager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/download.htm). When you add a dowload you can get the size of the file:

[image]

In your case the driver is 339MB. When you've already added the file to the Freedownloadmanager list you can select them and press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to get the size.