# OS X, how to know download file size

Tags: macos, file-download

I need to download [XQuartz-2.7.6.dmg](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/) file. Being on cellular internet I should know the size of the file before downloading it - it there any way know that in OS X?

I saw a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/293696/how-can-i-know-the-file-size-of-the-downloaded-file-before-downloading-it), but I cannot realise how to use the asnwer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as the link you post for similar question. Run curl command from terminal application. Here's an example output:

> # curl --head "http://xquartz-dl.macosforge.org/SL/XQuartz-2.7.6.dmg"
>   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Date: Sat, 26 Jul 2014 09:43:12 GMT
>   Server: Apache/2.2
>   Last-Modified: Sat, 17 May 2014 08:03:34 GMT
>   ETag: "2200b5-40d1599-4f993f776544f"
>   Accept-Ranges: bytes
>   Content-Length: **67966361**
>   Connection: close
>   Content-Type: application/x-apple-diskimage

Comment: where should I insert this command?

Comment: Terminal application